# Meterial Design Lite is not working with jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, jsp, material-design

I am working on spring boot project with jsp and meterial design lite. the jquery code looks like below.

```
 $.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/info/getform", function(data){
                $("#mainContent").html(data);
            }); 
    });
```

Material design lite code looks like below

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

The behavior of display when performing request with form
action attribute normal.
But while request performing with jquery ajax request to
backend generating same code. But text field is displaying
abnormal.

[material design lite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga7QL.png)

Answer (score 1):

adding "window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();" like as shown below solved my issue

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/info/getform", function(data){
                $("#mainContent").html(data);
                window.componentHandler.upgradeDom(); 
            }); 
    });
```